# Special characters are displaying on LCD Instead of numbers - Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to print the number pressed from the 4x3 matrix keypad to my 20x4 lcd but instead I got a w and arrow as a result.
[The error looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncf9a.jpg)
Here is my code.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);//RS,EN,D4,D5,D6,D7

const byte Rows= 4; //number of rows on the keypad i.e. 4
const byte Cols= 3; //number of columns on the keypad i,e, 3

//we will definne the key map as on the key pad:

char keymap[Rows][Cols]={
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rPins[Rows]= {9, 8, 7, 6}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte cPins[Cols]= {5, 4, 3}; //Columns 0 to 2

Keypad kpd= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rPins, cPins, Rows, Cols);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(20, 4);//initializing LCD
}

void loop() {
  char keypressed = kpd.getKey();
  if (keypressed != NO_KEY) {
    lcd.print(keypressed);
  }
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You need to debug it and work out where the problem is,  if `lcd.print("Hello World");` works, you know the problem is not in the LCD.  And if `Serial.println(keypressed);` gives you the correct result you know the problem isn't in the keypad.  My guess if you've got the wrong pin somewhere in your setup.

Comment: I've tried debugging the lcd and keypad individually using the same connections and it gives me the correct result. but when i've tried it together, it always displays 'w' and arrow symbol.

Comment: I bet you didn't try what I suggested with both configured at the same time though!  You are trying to use Pin 3, 4 & 5 for both the keypad and the LCD..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two modules share some of the same pins and that's at the root of the issue:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);//RS,EN,D4,D5,D6,D7
byte cPins[Cols]= {5, 4, 3}; //Columns 0 to 2
```

From these declarations, pins 5, 4 and 3 appear to be shared.   All sorts of weird things happen when pins are shared between peripheral devices.  Then when you say that each device seems to work well on its own, without the other... well I'd say the overlapping pins are your culprit.

See if there's a way to remap one or the other devices so as not to have shared pins.